# Why isn't change event fired on html radio input after the tick is removed by ticking another radio in the same group?

Tags: javascript, html, events

The question says it all. If it's a feature and not a bug, is there a way to overcome it? I found a good example elsewhere: http://jsfiddle.net/shaggyfrog/DUqYW/3/
In that example I would expect both alerts on click - one because the first radio looses it's tick and one because the other radio gets ticked.

Comment: Because the [change event](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#adef-onchange) requires a control to get focus, its value to change, then to lose focus. The only exception is that in some browsers, it will be dispatched when a radio button or checkbox is checked or unchecked and before losing focus.

Comment: That's the explanation I was looking for, why didn't you put it in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the change event to the group rather than the individual elements, this when then fire whenever any of the radio buttons in that group are changed:

```
$("[name='group1']").change(function () {
    alert("foo");
});
$("[name='group1']").change(function () {
    alert("bar");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DUqYW/4/